# Is it possible to open up certain web addresses using the default internet browser with python?

Tags: python, webaddress

I want python to open up a certain address using the computers default web browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely, use the [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module.

Comment: A little too terse. Edit your answer to something like "Use the webbrowser module", and I would be happy to vote for it.