# How to open url with the default web browser from terminal using Python?

Tags: python, windows, linux, macos, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to open up certain web addresses using the default internet browser with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039924/is-it-possible-to-open-up-certain-web-addresses-using-the-default-internet-brows)

I know OS X has an `open` command, where you can pass in a URL, and it'll open up the default browser and point it to the given domain.

But how would I go about doing this for other unix-based AND windows-based machines? Basically, I'd like to make a CLI (written in python), and have a cross-OS way of opening the browser from the terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html)

Comment: What's the point in giving the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4039928/95735) answer for the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4039924/95735) question over and over again?

Comment: @Piotr: Tell them to stop asking the same question then.

Comment: We can't tell them to stop but we certainly can and should close/delete them. But seeing how even high rep users don't care I think it's going to stay this way.

Answer (score 4):

"Unix" doesn't; OS X does.  Linux and *BSD, if they have the freedesktop.org stuff installed, should have `xdg-open` (and if you're lucky it will even do something sensible); Windows has `start` (as in, `start http://some.url` should work).  There are [better ways](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) to do this portably.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I just assumed it was for all unix-based machines, not just OS X.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

if os.name == 'posix':
    os.system("open "+str(website))
elif os.name == 'nt':
    os.system("start "+str(website))
```